# keep calayer from moving to original position

Tags: animation, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

```
   CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.33], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
[anim setKeyTimes:times];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(100., 100.)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(100., 200.)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(220., 200.)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(220., 100.)], nil];
anim.speed=1.0f;
[anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[anim setValues:values];
[anim setDuration:6.0]; 
[sublayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
```

I am able to get the CALayer to animate on the path yet after the animation the CALayer jumps back to the original position. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the position of the layer to the final position of the animation after adding the animation.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.33], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
[anim setKeyTimes:times];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(100., 100.)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(100., 200.)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(220., 200.)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(220., 100.)], nil];
anim.speed=1.0f;
[anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[anim setValues:values];
[anim setDuration:6.0]; 
[sublayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
[sublayer.layer.position = [[values lastObject] CGPointValue];// this will set the position to the final position of the animation, (220., 100.);
```